# Using Vagrant/Ansible to spin up a multi-node kubernetes cluster fails detecting kubelet file

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, vagrant

I am following instructions on [site](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/03/15/kubernetes-setup-using-ansible-and-vagrant/)  to spin up a multi-node kubernetes cluster using vagrant/ansible. Unfortunately, I get following error:

```
TASK [Configure node ip] *******************************************************
fatal: [k8s-master]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Destination /etc/default/kubelet does not exist !", "rc": 257}
```

The relevant passage in the Vagrantfile is:

```
- name: Install Kubernetes binaries
    apt:
      name: "{{ packages }}"
      state: present
      update_cache: yes
    vars:
      packages:
        - kubelet
        - kubeadm
        - kubectl

  - name: Configure node ip
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/default/kubelet
      line: KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--node-ip={{ node_ip }}
```

Is it just the wrong path? Which one would it be then ?

P.S.: I also get a warning beforehand indicating:

```
[WARNING]: Could not find aptitude. Using apt-get instead
```

Is it not installing the kubelet package and might that be the reason why it doesn't find the file ? How to fix it in that case ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Updating the node ip in the config file is not required. If you still wanted to change for any specific reason, below is the solution.

You can change the file to `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf` as per the [change](https://github.com/kubernetes/release/issues/654)

Before you change, please check if this file exists in the nodes.

`/etc/default/kubelet` is for yum package.